# Where are real limits of evaporative cooling?

Tags: water, home-experiment, evaporation, cooling

There are many projects focused on utilising evaporative cooling for [food preservation](http://www.chelseagreen.com/content/project-evaporative-cooler-box-draft/) or [computer cooling](http://www.ku74.net/uberbong/) purposes. I have other thing in mind, however and that's cooling beer.

Once you're outside, off grid, you can't use high energy consuming methods such as classical refrigerator or Peltier modules. Water pump sounds like much energy consuming method, but is it capable to make significant temperature difference? Are there any real limits to evaporative cooling?

Comment: It won't work well because you want your beer to be cold. Evporative cooling makes things not very hot.

Comment: There are limits to all cooling methods. Can you cool beer just by evaporating water to an appropriate temperature? I don't think so, but that's because I like my beer really cold. If all you want is a couple of degrees below room temperature and the air is reasonably dry, then it might just work for you. Personally, I would put up a solar panel and a small fridge or, if you don't have sun, bring a small generator.